# How to find out the dependency paths?

Tags: debian, package-management

For example, there are packages and their dependencies:

```
a -> b (a require b)
b -> c & d
x -> a
y -> x
z -> x
z -> x & y
```

Now, give `c` and `z`, there are two dependency paths:

```
z -> x -> a -> b -> c
z -> y -> x -> a -> b -> c
```

The question is how to find out the dependency paths between two specific Debian packages?

P.S. The idea behind is to draw the dependency graph for a given set of packages, include the intermediate ones missing in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

Your overall problem might already be solved by using `apt-cache dotty`.

If you want to implement it yourself, use some graph algorithm to find a path.  Or check the source code of apt-cache. ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I should describe it more clearly, `apt-cache dotty`  creates the graph for a given set of packages, no more no less. And what's my object is to add the implicit dependents in the graph.